# How to Make Pardot Authorisation Request?

Tags: api, error, authentication, pardot, post

I have a training org where I'm making API callouts for authorise to the Pardot environement, but recieving the error :-
Error Code :- 49
Error :- Access Denied,

The details of the API url which I'm hitting are mentioned below :-

API Method :- POST

POST Url :- https://pi.pardot.com/api/login/version/3?email=jitesh.goel@domain.com&password=Pass@abcd&user_key=12345678986abcba59578479cf412345

When I tried the same for one of my other training orgs it returned me the API key but in this scenario it is returning me the error mentioned above.

Please let me know if there is any specific update/enhancement in the API request which I have to make to get the API key or any kind of permission which I have to assign to the user for the same.

Answer (score 3):

Not so long ago, Pardot changed the authentication method so that you can no longer put the username and password in the URL of the request. You need to put them in the request body.

See the current documentation here: http://developer.pardot.com/#authentication

In particular:

> IMPORTANT: Support for passing credentials via querystring is
>   deprecated and will be forbidden in a future version of the API.
>   Please update your API client as soon as possible.